# How to convert vector in to an array?

Tags: octave

I want to convert vector into an array in Ocatve. 
I want to compare a string available in a vector or not. The vector is predefined. I am going to use strcmp function to check for the existance of a particular string in the list. This function works only with arrays, but not with vectors.

How can we convert a vector into an array in octave?

Please, find the difference between vector and arrays using strcmp in below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Actually, if I am using strcmp function with arrays means I will get the result in single step. Otherwise I have to iterate over the loop.

Comment: please add a MCVE

Comment: a vector ***is*** itself an array

Comment: This question makes no sense. Please show some code for what you want to do that doesn't work, and copy-paste also the error message into the question. It's always better to show than to tell.

Comment: Your "vector" is a 2D char array (try using `size` on it). Your "array" is a cell array of char arrays. You can convert the first into the second using `array=cellstr(vector)`.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you went through the trouble of uploading a screen shot, isn't it easier to copy-paste the text from the Octave window into the question? It certainly is easier for people that want to help you, if they can copy-paste the code from your question, rather than having to type it in.

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo. This is what I want. It's working. Thanks again. And I am sorry for uploading screenshot. Hereafter when I post my question I will copy, paste my code.

Comment: Please read the basic [Octave documentation for strings and characters](https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/Strings.html). That will explain this. And if you read the Matlab documentation while doing so, be aware that Octave differs in significant ways: in Matlab, double-quoted string literals are `string` objects (which don't exist in Octave), while in Octave they're plain `char` arrays. And Octave will auto-pad char arrays when vertically concatenating (like your `['hi';'hello']` example), where Matlab will not.

Comment: This discussion prompted me to write a blog post with my understanding of the Matlab string situation. Maybe you'll find it useful: [String Representation in Matlab is a Mess](http://blog.apjanke.net/2019/04/20/matlab-string-representation-is-a-mess.html)

Comment: Sure @AndrewJanke. I will go through your blog post. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Octave (and Matlab) do not have vector *types*. They also do not have list *types*.

What they do have are arrays, and cell arrays.
Both have 2 dimensions or more by convention.

A "horizontal vector" in octave is effectively a 2D array where the first dimension (i.e. rows) is 1.

A "vertical / column vector" in octave is effectively a 2D array where the second dimension (i.e. columns) is 1.

A "scalar" is a 2D array where the first and second dimensions are both 1.

Octave / matlab provides functions to test if an array is effectively a 'vector' or a 'scalar', but they are not considered as separate 'types'. So the question of converting a 'vector' to an equivalent 'array' does not make sense.

An array has the restriction that all its elements must be of the same type (e.g. numerical, character, class-derived objects, etc)

A cell array has no such restriction; each element of the cell array can have any type, including a numerical array or another cell array.

It sounds like what you want is to create a cell array, where you make each element a string.

You should be able to take it from there.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou at least they copied broadcasting (I think they call it  implicit expansion) exactly how GNU Octave has done it

Comment: @Tasos: "I like how inventive matlab gets when trying to make octave incompatible". I bet soon they'll make a new operator `#`, just for giggles.

Comment: Hi @TasosPapastylianou,
Thanks for your response. Really informative. I have added a screenshot in the question above. Can you please check the difference between the behaviour of arrays and vector in the image?

I have mentioned my problem clearly. I will repeat my question once again.
I am having a vector 
    ['hi', 'hello', 'good', 'bad'] 
I want to check whether a given string say 'hello' available in the vector or not. I am using strcmp, but it is not giving me a useful output.
But, arrays are really helpful:
    {'hi', 'hello', 'good', 'bad'}
That's why I wanted to know any way

Comment: You might want to clarify one thing: in Matlab and Octave, unlike most languages, arrays are not distinct from scalars. So when you say "they do have are arrays, and cell arrays", you might also add "and they don't have any types which are _not_ arrays". I've found that this is the big issue that confuses novice Matlab/Octave programmers.

Comment: @ShankarMuthusamy: Be careful with your example code here. You say `['hi', 'hello', 'good', 'bad']` in your comment, but your code has `['hi'; 'hello'; 'good'; 'bad']`. These are different! Commas make horizontal concatenation, and semicolons make vertical concatenation. Thus, `['hi'; 'hello'; 'good'; 'bad']` actually is a vector, but it's just one single long string, which is not what you want. `['hi'; 'hello'; 'good'; 'bad']` is not a vector: it is a 2-D cell array, with padding. Also not what you want.

Comment: @ShankarMuthusamy: When you say "arrays are really helpful: {'hi', 'hello', 'good', 'bad'}", don't call that an "array". _Everything_ in Octave is an array. What is distinctive about `{'hi', 'hello', ...}` is that it is a _cell_, because of the curly braces. Cells are like pointers or containers; they can hold other arrays, which may be of mixed types. A cell array that contains just char vectors in its cells is called a "cellstr", and is usually the best way to store strings in Octave.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Oh, come on. :) Don't give Matlab crap for making an incompatible string type. The double-quoted `string` object is one of the best things Matlab has done in years (up there with `table` and `datetime`), because all the other ways of representing strings in Matlab _suck_.

Comment: @ShankarMuthusamy: Here's another way of looking at it. In Octave, "vector" is not a _type_. "Vector" is a word we use to describe the _shape_ of an array. Any array that is 1 element long in all dimensions except for one is called a "vector". You can think of it as "vector" being the word for a one-dimensional array in Octave. (Except they're not _really_ one-dimensional, because all Octave arrays are actually at least 2-D, so to do a 1-D array we just make it 1 long along one dimension and then ignore that dimension.)

Comment: @AndrewJanke, as you told I have made typo errors in my above comment. And thanks for sharing many informations. Your comment is really helpful.